# Is there any easy way to toggle "do/end" and "{}" in ruby in Vim?

Tags: vim, textmate, ruby, macvim

Is there any easy way to toggle "do/end" and "{}" in ruby in Vim?

(TextMate does this with `^{`.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You'd have to either use searchpair(), or to play with % (as long as matchit is installed, and as you are on begin/end), then mark the two positions, test whether it's text or brackets, and finally update the two lines.

```
nnoremap <buffer> <c-x>{ :call <sid>ToggleBeginOrBracket()<cr>

let s:k_be = [ 'begin', 'end' ]
function! s:ToggleBeginOrBracket()
  let c = lh#position#char_at_mark('.')
  if c =~ '[{}]'
    " don't use matchit for {,}
    exe 'normal! %s'.s:k_be[1-(c=='}')]."\<esc>``s".s:k_be[(c=='}')]."\<esc>"
  else
    let w = expand('<cword>')
    if w == 'begin'
      " use mathit
      normal %
      exe "normal! ciw}\<esc>``ciw{\<esc>"
    elseif w == 'end'
      " use mathit
      normal %
      exe "normal! ciw{\<esc>``ciw}\<esc>"
    else
      throw 'Cannot toggle block: cursor is not on {, }, begin, nor end'
    endif
  endif
endfunction
```

Where `lh#position#char_at_mark()` is defined [here](http://code.google.com/p/lh-vim/source/browse/vim-lib/trunk/autoload/lh/position.vim#67).

PS: this is definitively a SO question as it combines ruby context, and advanced vim scripting.

Comment: Yeah, there's no reason for the complicated solution.  Just use matchit.vim. :)

Comment: Matchit does not solve OP's request. (And even without vim involded, it still concerns the tuning of a development tool, for development purposes)

Answer (score 4):

Check out this new plugin: https://github.com/jgdavey/vim-blockle.

30 chars pad

Answer (score 1):

There is a [splitjoin.vim](https://github.com/AndrewRadev/splitjoin.vim) plugin that does this nicely (gJ/gS mappings for splitting/joining).